# Uniform elliptic condition

Tags: matrices, analysis, elliptic-equations, elliptic-operators

The definition of uniform elliptic condition. Given  an $n \times n$-matrix $A(x)$ depending on some $x$ sometimes I see it framed as
$$\lambda I \leq A(x) \leq  \Lambda I$$
for $\lambda, \Lambda >0$, i.e. $$\lambda |v|^2 \leq v^T A(x)v \leq  \Lambda |v|^2$$  and other times as
$$\lambda I \leq A(x)$$
Are the two notions equivalent?

Comment: Well, if $A(x)$ is continuous and the domain $\Omega \ni x$ is compact then the other bound is trivial. Is this your setting?

Comment: Yes thank you for pointing it out